# NullPointerException in Java ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I can't for the life of me figure this out!
It says there's a null pointer exception at line 20, which is this line.

```
walls.add(new Wall(random.nextInt(20), random.nextInt(20)));
```

Have I declared it incorrectly? What am I doing wrong?  Is it one of those things where it's so stupid that I was just simply blind?

Here is the full code:

```
package com.astar.world;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import com.astar.objects.Player;
import com.astar.objects.Wall;

public class World {

private Player player;
private List<Wall> walls;
private Random random;

public World() {
    player = new Player(2, 2);
    walls = new ArrayList<Wall>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        walls.add(new Wall(random.nextInt(20), random.nextInt(20)));
    }
}

public void update(float deltaTime) {

}

public Player getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

public List<Wall> getWalls() {
    return walls;
}
```

}

Here is the error:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.astar.world.World.(World.java:20)  at
>   com.astar.screens.GameScreen.(GameScreen.java:13)   at
>   com.astar.game.AStarAlgoGame.create(AStarAlgoGame.java:11)    at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`random` is not initialized so the `NullPointerException` occurs.

To resolve this just go

```
private Random random = new Random();
```

Comment: Why -1 to this answer?

Comment: From posters who think you shouldn't answer the question because it was too simple to ask.  Ignore it and move on.

Comment: instantiated would be the more appropriate word instead of initialized

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you instantiating the variable `random` in your code.

Comment: instantiating would be the more appropriate word instead of initializing